# How can I display WordPress posts in Flutter app?

Tags: wordpress, flutter, dart

I am trying to implement a simple discussion board in my Flutter app. To do this, I wanted to connect a WordPress blog site to the app. I followed [this tutorial](https://medium.com/flutter-community/building-flutter-apps-with-wordpress-backend-part-1-e56414a4a79b) and slightly edited to get my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_wordpress/flutter_wordpress.dart' as wp;
import 'package:flutter_html/flutter_html.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'package:azingg_starter/MomTalk_Home/wp_details.dart';

class LandingPage extends StatelessWidget {
  wp.WordPress wordPress = wp.WordPress(
    baseUrl: 'https://example.com/',
  );

  _fetchPosts() {
    Future<List<wp.Post>> posts = wordPress.fetchPosts(
        postParams: wp.ParamsPostList(
          context: wp.WordPressContext.view,
          pageNum: 1,
          perPage: 10,
        ),
        fetchAuthor: true,
        fetchFeaturedMedia: true,
        fetchComments: true);
    if (posts == null) {
      return posts;
    }
  }

  _getPostImage(wp.Post post) {
    if (post.featuredMedia == null) {
      return SizedBox();
    }
    return Image.network(post.featuredMedia.sourceUrl);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('MomTalk'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: _fetchPosts(),
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<wp.Post>> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none) {
              return Container();
            }
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                wp.Post post = snapshot.data[index];
                return InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => DetailsPage(post)));
                  },
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                    child: Card(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            _getPostImage(post),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 10,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              post.title.rendered.toString(),
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 15,
                            ),
                            Html(
                              data: post.excerpt.rendered.toString(),
                              onLinkTap: (String link) {
                                _launchUrl(link);
                              },
                            ),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(post.date.toString().replaceAll('T', ' ')),
                                Text(post.author.name),
                              ],
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

_launchUrl(String link) async {
  if (await canLaunch(link)) {
    await launch(link);
  } else {
    throw 'Cannot launch $link';
  }
}
```

Previously, I was getting an error about "the getter 'length' was called on null", so I added the "if (posts == null)" line of code to solve this. However, now I am getting a blank screen (even though I have posts in my site). Any ideas on why it seems to think there are no posts in my site, or why it is not getting them?

Comment: `_fetchPosts` should be an async method? and you have to await the call..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of `_fetchPosts` has a number of issues.

First, make it `async`. This will make waiting on futures within it a lot more intuitive.

Second, await `wordPress.fetchPosts`. Right now you are calling it directly which will just return a list of futures, and you can't use futures directly to populate your page.

Third, you have a typo in this code:

```dart
if (posts == null) {
  return posts;
}
```

This will mean you only return `posts` when it is null. When `posts` is not null, the function won't return anything, and in Dart, functions will always return null if they aren't returning anything else. As a result, this function will always return null. As such, you could just change `==` to `!=`, but that would then introduce a redundancy as you will only return `posts` when it isn't null but the function would then return null anyway. As such, you could do away with the if check entirely. (This is assuming you are not working with null safety, which your code would suggest you are not.)

With these considerations, the full function should look like this:

```dart
Future<List<wp.Post>> _fetchPosts() async {
  List<wp.Post> posts = await wordPress.fetchPosts(
    postParams: wp.ParamsPostList(
      context: wp.WordPressContext.view,
      pageNum: 1,
      perPage: 10,
    ),
    fetchAuthor: true,
    fetchFeaturedMedia: true,
    fetchComments: true,
  );

  return posts;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have tested it and still got the error "the getter 'length' was called on null", but this time it seems I need to adjust the FutureBuilder. Here is the error: 'The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder<List<Post>>(dirty, state:
I/flutter ( 6968): _FutureBuilderState<List<Post>>#21141):
I/flutter ( 6968): The getter 'length' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 6968): Receiver: null
I/flutter ( 6968): Tried calling: length
I/flutter ( 6968):
I/flutter ( 6968): The relevant error-causing widget was:
I/flutter ( 6968):   FutureBuilder<List<Post>>'

Comment: @AllyZ Then your problem is that `_fetchPosts` is returning null and you aren't properly handling that.

Comment: ok, the only options I can think of are to check that the WordPress website is not blocking the ability to get the data, or that it is not actually saving my posts in a sub-page or something like that. In the meantime, if you have any other recommendations they are welcome!

Comment: @AllyZ The primary option is to check `snapshot.hasData` and if it's false, display something else.